# How to use variables in text function in pgzero

Tags: python, text, pgzero

In my game, I want to make a score function. How to make it to display variables in the pgzero text funtion

the code to display text is:
`screen.draw.text(score, (70, 30), color="orange")`
but an error comes up like this: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'`

how can I display a variable in the `screen.draw.text` function?

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a string to the `text` function. Your `score` variable probably contains an int value. Use the `str` function to convert the contents of the `score` variable to a string:

```
screen.draw.text(str(score), (70, 30), color="orange")
```